# Possible to ensure that from address is not spoofed by mail server?

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I want to know that is it possible that using postfix or any other MTA, i can apply a restriction that email sender cannot change/spoof his sender email, and email is only sent from the email ID, through which it was authenticated.

thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: to stop spam....

Comment: Spam you receive, spam others receive from you, or spam others receive that claims to be from you but isn't really?

Comment: i want to apply this restriction for senders i have with me.

Comment: Forcing the email to bear their real address won't stop it being sent.  Sure, it'll mean you can track it back to the sender later - but if you have your mail server logs and require SMTP AUTH, you can do that without restricting sender address.  I think you should rewrite this question and ask about what you want to do, instead of asking for details of how you think you ought to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know that is it possible that using postfix or any other MTA, i can apply a restriction that email sender cannot change/spoof his sender email, and email is only sent from the email ID, through which it was authenticated.

yes, it possible. You can use [smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) with [reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch)

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
 reject_unknown_sender_domain,
 reject_unlisted_sender,
 reject_unverified_sender

smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_logins_maps

/etc/postfix/sender_logins_maps
user@example.net sasl_login_name1
```

Answer (score 2):

In [`main.cf`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) you'll want [`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) as part of your [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions). You'll then need to define [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps). The use case you're describing can be done easily with with either a [`regex table`](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) or [`prce table`](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html).