# Postfix SMTP authentication FROM

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp

I have a Postfix server with authentication running. However I recently found out, that anyone authenticated may send mail from any account. Meaning user1 is logging in and may send the e-mail from user2@domain.com

Is there a way to "bind" user1 only to send mail from user1@domain.com (and his assigned account alias)? Thank you.

Comment: See also: [Possible to ensure that from address is not spoofed by mail server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/536659/possible-to-ensure-that-from-address-is-not-spoofed-by-mail-server)